# How can list elements be looped under <script> in sightly?

Tags: javascript, java, osgi, aem, sightly

In my html page I would like to loop through the properties returned by my Java class but do it under `<script>` tag.

Currently my html page has this:

```
<div id="map_wrapper">
<div    data-sly-use.ev="Foo"
        class="mapping"
        id="${ev.googleClass || ''"
        >
</div>
</div>

<script>
   ....
              var markers = [                
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
              ];
  .....
</script>
```

My Java Class has following getters:

```
//returns [0] = "something, -33.89, 151.2" [1] = "beach, -33.9, 15.02" etc.
public List<String> getVals() {
    return vals;
}

public String getGoogleClass() {
    if (vals.size() == 0)
        return "";
    return "map_canvas";
}
```

**Question**

How can I replace the values in `markers` variable in `<script>` tag with values returned from `getVals()`?

Answer (score 5):

No. For generating JSON, in Java I'd use the [JSONStringer](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/commons/json/io/JSONStringer.html), or in server-side JavaScript that would be `JSON.stringify`, in order to avoid doing that with the template.

For example, the template file could do something like that:

```
<script data-sly-use.logic="logic.js">
    var markers = ${logic.json @ context='unsafe'}
</script>
```

And the corresponding logic.js file would do:

```
use(function () {
    var myObj = {
        foo: "bar",
        arr: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    };

    return {
        json: JSON.stringify(myObj)
    };
});
```

Even better for a good separation of concerns would be to avoid inline scripts altogether, which would also remove the worrying context='unsafe' that's needed here. The best is usually to put this into a data attribute, which are precisely made for that. So your template would then look as follows:

```
<div id="map_wrapper"
     data-sly-use.logic="logic.js"
     data-markers="${logic.json}">
    ...
</div>
```

It might look that the JSON gets unnecessary escaping, but you don't need to mind about them, HTML will handle them just fine. You can try out my above example with the REPL live Sightly evaluation environment:
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sightly-repl

Comment: Your approach looks better, but in your example...How would values for json array be populated from a java method (`getVals()` in my case)? I like the separation of concerns you proposed but what I'm really after is being able to fill a JS array with values from java class.

Comment: What API does build the values returned by getVals? This is what you'd have to call in the for loop. Or the other way around would be that you implement another getJsonVals() in your Java object that would build a JSON string as my little JS did.

Comment: The Java class I'm using is extending `WCMUse` I've posted the entire Java class and HTML page as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/e84477e20985c2b7bcab

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at it later tonight.

Comment: Much appreciate it. I'm new to sightly and a bit confused. As I read your solution in more detail, I think you are proposing that I use JS as the backend rather than Java. I would much prefer to keep it Java because I will have to change a lot of code otherwise.

Comment: Yes I proposed server-side JS, because I originally didn't realize that you use Java for component logic, but Java is just as fine. In Java you can do the exact same thing, but obviously syntax differs.

Answer (score -2):

You could create a java slingservlet that exposes the data, and hit the servlet with ajax inside the script tag.

[Here's a bit of a guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom-sling-servlets.html)