# Sightly jstl c:set analog

Tags: java, aem, sightly

On jsp I can write following code:

```
<c:set var="salary"  value="${object.salary}"/>
```

and then in code I can use `${salary}` variable

Can you help to rewrite it using sightly?

P.S.

I tried this:

```
<div data-sly-use.salary="MySalary">
    <div data-sly-use.product="MyBean"  data-sly-unwrap>
        {
        <ul data-sly-list="${product.specifications}" data-sly-unwrap>
                "${item.sku ? item.sku : 'product'}" : "${item.label} ${item.value}"<div data-sly-test="${!itemList.last}" data-sly-unwrap>,</div>
        </ul>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bla-bla="${salary}"></div>
```

But I see compilation error

Comment: It looks like you're trying to generate JSON with Sightly. Sightly is not made for that and programming languages should not be mixed within the same file. I'd recommend you to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144652/how-can-list-elements-be-looped-under-script-in-sightly/31145336#31145336

Comment: @ Gabriel Walt I saw question where towers of Hanoi was developed using  sightly

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the feature of assigning variables in Sightly. The maximum that is possible is comparing values, else all your logic goes into the Java or JavaScript `Use-API` classes.

When you are using `data-sly-use`, the value provided must either be

1. Java class that extends the `WCMUse` class or implements the `Use` interface or
2. JavaScript file that defines the use class.

Hence you receive a compilation error when the value of `data-sly-use` is neither of the above two.

However, I can suggest a workaround for your question, though I wouldn't recommend using the same.
You can make use of `data-sly-test` and assign a variable name to that, which can later be used elsewhere.

For example.

```
<div data-sly-test.salary="MySalary"></div>
<div>
    <div data-sly-use.product="MyBean"  data-sly-unwrap>
        {
        <ul data-sly-list="${product.specifications}" data-sly-unwrap>
                "${item.sku ? item.sku : 'product'}" : "${item.label} ${item.value}"<div data-sly-test="${!itemList.last}" data-sly-unwrap>,</div>
        </ul>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bla-bla="${salary}"></div>
```

Comment: I need assign content of **<div data-sly-use.product="MyBean"  data-sly-unwrap> ...** rather than just string **"MySalary"**

Comment: You can access the values of the bean using the name `product` as mentioned in the syntax. If you need some value of the bean in another variable then the syntax is still the same `<div data-sly-test.salary="${ product.salary }"></div>`

Comment: @rakhi4110, you're correct, and you probably also agree that this is kind of abusing the language for things that it intentionally doesn't allow. The variables that the template needs should be prepared with the Use-API, and the template shouldn't need such hacks.

Comment: @GabrielWalt completely agree with you. And that's the reason I mentioned I wouldn't recommend it. However, this is not a hack that only I am suggesting. The [docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#test) itself mentions using this for constructing if-else logic, by storing the output in a variable :)